# Tweepy stream filter with both follow and track

Tags: twitter, tweepy

In my streamlistener, the stream.filter is somehow broken. I can either `track` specific user, or `track` certain keywords. Is there anyway that I can do both at the same time? Also, `track` always take precedent regardless position.

```
stream.filter(follow=['27674', '37827168', '35220'], track=['keyword'])
```

Comment: It isn't broken - it works that way by design. Why can you not follow the users, and filter the data you receive to find which tweets contain the keyword(s)?

Comment: I'm just wondering, if there anything official anywhere on this? Because I would have imagined that one could stream by *both* the `follow` and `track` arguments at the same time.